# App is Crashing while opening gmail from android app on clicking a button

Tags: android, gmail-api

i have a ImageViewbutton which opens gmail **compose mail tab** in my android app,**via intent**.
Previously the same code was working for opening it.

```
  imageView3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent send=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                send.setType("plain/text");
                send.setData(Uri.parse("testmail@gmail.com"));
                send.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail");
                startActivity(send);

            }
        });
```

Now the app gets crashed after clicking on the button.

Comment: Please paste your crash logs here.

Comment: @vishal ,sorry i am not using emulator

Comment: You can check error logs into your IDE (like Android Studio or Eclipse) @Sarthakpandit

Comment: You can view your logs on 'Android Monitor' window(in Android studio) and on LogCat(in Eclipse).

Comment: @Ronak, i am not running the app on emulator,its on a real device,

Comment: Yes but on real devices you can view logs.

Comment: the error log remains empty,since android studio was only used for making the apk file,i did not run it on emulator.

Comment: can anyone tell me the answer for the question ,i asked.Are any changes needs to be made on the package of gmail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally i Got the answer,it was really hectic for that piece of code to make that work**

```
      Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/html");
            final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            final List<ResolveInfo> matches = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
            ResolveInfo best = null;
            for (final ResolveInfo info : matches) {
                if (info.activityInfo.packageName.endsWith(".gm") || info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains("gmail")) {
                    best = info;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (best != null) {
                intent.setClassName(best.activityInfo.packageName, best.activityInfo.name);
            }

            intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:emailto@gmail.com"));


            try {
                startActivity(intent);

            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error Sending Email,Try Later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

replace your code with this. if your app not crashing anymore it means you have not Gmail app in your android device.

```
imageView3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
           {
               try
               {
                   Intent send=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                   send.setType("plain/text");
                   send.setData(Uri.parse("testmail@gmail.com"));
                   send.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail");
                   startActivity(send);
                }
                catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

        }
    });
```

Comment: no the app is crashing,and yeah gmail can't be uninstalled until the phone is rooted,and thats not in my case.

Comment: I can not help you until you put your crash-logs here.